# unexpected symbol 'end of file'

Tags: unity-game-engine

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject player;

private Vector3 offset;

void Start ()
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a }

Answer (score 1):

As Flaming Zombie stated, you are missing a curly brace. Below should work for you.

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public GameObject player;

    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start ()
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }    
}
```